# " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jose' " ; but it's already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, jose, python-jose

```
Process SpawnProcess-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\gveda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Programs\FastAPI\.\Blog\main.py", line 4, in <module>    from .routers import blog,user,auth
  File "D:\Programs\FastAPI\.\Blog\routers\auth.py", line 3, in <module>         from .. import schemas,database,models,token
  File "D:\Programs\FastAPI\.\Blog\token.py", line 2, in <module>
    from jose import JWTError, jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jose'
```

I have already installed python-jose module still it is giving me the error that there is module named jose.
From jose module I am importing jwt and there is no module of it. Why ??

I already installed python-jose and jose modules separately still the same error occurs.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python executables on your system (e.g. older versions)?

Comment: @9769953 yes I do have anaconda which has python 3.9 and i have python 3.10 separately.

Comment: If you're using the command line, try `python3.10 -m pip install python-jose` instead. That'll guarantee the package is installed for that particular Python executable.

Comment: If you're using Conda, you might try and install it with Conda instead. But if the above works, that means you've somehow set your environment incorrectly: Conda should take care of `pip` being the correct pip.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common mistake and it all stems from environment variables.
The problem is that when you write `pip` in you command line, it points to a path to a certain `pip.exe` that could be `python/3.9/lib/pip.exe` `python/3.11/lib/pip.exe`, `python/3.x/lib/pip.exe` or any other version of python installed on your machine. So it's likely you installed your lib with a different pip then the one linked to the python executable you are calling your script with.

So either you change your environment variables to something like `pip39` and `pip311` or you call the specific pip like so:

## Windows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>where python
C:\Python311\python.exe
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Thanks to `where` we are able to find all instances of python on our machine.

Then all you need to do is call pip like so:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Python311\python.exe -m pip install my_desired_lib
```

Now when you call your script you should specify which executable you want to use.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Python311\python.exe my_script.py
```

## Linux

For the `where` function use `whereis`. Apart from that using python is the same, so calling a specific `pip` and running your script with a specific `python.exe` is the same.

I hope this will help someone!

Comment: If this a Conda environment, why then does Conda not set the path(s) correctly?

Comment: I don't use Conda so I can't say for sure, but when ever I use some kind of virtual env, like with pycharm it takes quite a bit of configuration to get right. I tend to use the command line for package installs and calling my scripts, it's more straight forwards and isn't any more time consuming once you got the hang of it. In any case when you want to install a package with pip it's good practice to check `pip --version`  which will retrun something like this `pip 23.0 from C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)` so you can tell what python version it is linked to.